# How can I bring xampp control panel setting to desktop, in Ubuntu?

Tags: xampp

I am running lampp on ubuntu 64 bit system, I am finding problem to start xampp server every time.

Comment: its better to start and stop the xampp from terminal.

Comment: @MohamdAl-Najjar, I am talking on ubuntu, inside lampp folder no such xampp control panel where we can start and stop things. Check my answer below to do this things

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to install gksu with the following command:

**sudo apt-get install gksu**
Then, run:

**gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/xampp-control-panel.desktop**

and save the following code in the file.

(You are using 64 bit system so there is no need to change anything, simply do copy paste)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=XAMPP Control Panel
Comment=Start and Stop XAMPP
Exec=gksudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
Icon=/opt/lampp/htdocs/favicon.ico
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Note: For 32 bit xampp type "manager-linux.run" at place of "manager-linux-x64.run"

Run following command in terminal:

**sudo apt-get update**

Now check applications, its icon has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to this [article](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/), gksu is deprecated. It is removed from Debian, Ubuntu 18.04 and other newer Linux distribution version.